# A question regarding the definition of an argument.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

MY textbook states the following -

*To say that an argument form is valid means that no matter what particular statements are substituted for the statement variables in its premises, if the resulting premises are all true, then the conclusion is also true. To say that an argument is valid means that its form is valid.*

Is it correct to say the following -
*To say that an argument form is valid means that no matter what particular statements are substituted for the statement variables in its premises, if the resulting premises are all false, then the conclusion is also false.*

Comment: No, the truth of the premises implies that of the conclusion, but formally an argument with contradictory premises and true conclusion is valid. See Principle of Explosion (aka: Ex Falso).

Comment: Do you mean the definition of "conclusion" in the sense it is usually used in the "real life" or the mathematical "conclusion" ? Anyway, for an ARGUMENT to be valid, it is not enough that the conclusion is valid, the premises must be it as well. Otherwise we would have to accept every nonsense just because it can be "derived" from wrong premises. This would make every argument meaningless.

Comment: In short, the conclusion is something else than the whole argument.

Answer (score -2):

No, it’s not correct to say that if the premises are false, the conclusion is false. Let me give an example to illustrate. Consider the following argument:

1. If I can teleport, then the Collatz Conjecture is true.
2. I can teleport.
3. Therefore, the Collatz Conjecture is true.

The argument form is clearly valid, but the two premises here are both wrong. **However**, this does **not** mean that the Collatz Conjecture is false.

Comment: If your second premise is false, then your first premise is true (interpreting "if ... then ..." as material implication, which I think is the approprate reading here).

Comment: I don’t see how the invalidity of the second premise means the first premise is true. And yes, the “if… then” is material implication

Comment: If the antecedent is false, then the material implication is true.